# How to enumerate vertices in a graph

Tags: java, data-structures, graph

Given a graph G that I have to make a square product of and make graph H. Graph H will consist of all possible pairs of vertices in G. Basically, a Cartesian product on graph G to produce graph H.
in the pseudo code, i am told to build the square H of G by enumerating all pairs of vertices in G in o(n^2) time then construction edges for a total of o(n^3). However i don't understand what is meant by enumerating all pairs of vertices, can someone please explain it to me? Thanks

Comment: This might be useful for you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15575/square-of-a-graph

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple nested for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i){
    final GraphNode n1 = getGraphNode(i);
    for(int j = i + i; j < n; ++j) {
        final GraphNode n2 = getGraphNode(j);
        addPair(n1, n2);
    }
}
```

It may not be a "simple" for loop like the above, but that's basically the idea.